# What is the meaning of "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node'"?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to make an SVG Line using JavaScript, but I keep getting an error that I don't understand . The Chrome console says,

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Below is my code:

```js
function play(x, y) {
  var line1 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
  line1.setAttribute('x1', x - 25);
  line1.setAttribute('x2', x + 25);
  line1.setAttribute('y1', y - 25);
  line1.setAttribute('y2', y + 25);
  line1.setAttribute('stroke', 'white');
  line1.setAttribute('stroke-width', '2');

  var line2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
  line2.setAttribute('x1', x + 25);
  line2.setAttribute('x2', x - 25);
  line2.setAttribute('y1', y + 25);
  line2.setAttribute('y2', y - 25);
  line2.setAttribute('stroke', 'white');
  line2.setAttribute('stroke-width', '2');

  document.getElementById('game').appendChild(line1);
  document.getElementById('game').appendChild(line2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tic-tac-toe</title>
</head>

<body style='background-color: black; margin: 0px;'>
  <svg id='game' width='300' height='300' style='margin: auto; position: relative; top: 50px; display: block; background-color: #000; border: 2px solid white;'>
        <rect x='0' y='0' width='100' height='100' style='stroke-width: 2; stroke: #fff' onclick='play(50, 50);'/>
        <rect x='100' y='0' width='100' height='100' style='stroke-width: 2; stroke: #fff' onclick=''/>
        <rect x='200' y='0' width='100' height='100' style='stroke-width: 2; stroke: #fff' onclick=''/>
        <rect x='0' y='100' width='100' height='100' style='stroke-width: 2; stroke: #fff' onclick=''/>
        <rect x='100' y='100' width='100' height='100' style='stroke-width: 2; stroke: #fff' onclick=''/>
        <rect x='200' y='100' width='100' height='100' style='stroke-width: 2; stroke: #fff' onclick=''/>
        <rect x='0' y='200' width='100' height='100' style='stroke-width: 2; stroke: #fff' onclick=''/>
        <rect x='100' y='200' width='100' height='100' style='stroke-width: 2; stroke: #fff' onclick=''/>
  <rect x='200' y='200' width='100' height='100' style='stroke-width: 2; stroke: #fff' onclick=''/>
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

An X is supposed to appear when you click on the top-left box. One line appears, but another perpendicular line should appear. I just want to know why it isn't working, how to fix it, and what the error means. Thanks!

Comment: You said that on chrome nothing appears, but your example run on chrome seems to replicate what is happening in the snippet

Comment: I do not understand your question: Do you think debuggers give fancy error messages?

Comment: @Snel23 yes, I just saw this, I must've forgotten to save my code. But, another perpendicular line should appear

Comment: @MisterJojo Yes, that's what the Chrome Debugger is. It just says some weird thing that only a few people can understand. What I'm asking is why isn't another perpendicular line appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing around with your code, it looks like the lines are drawing on top of each other. It looks like you have set the `X` values incorrectly for `line2`. If you change the code for `line2` to the following, it will work.

```
    var line2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
    line2.setAttribute('x1', x - 25);
    line2.setAttribute('x2', x + 25);
    line2.setAttribute('y1', y + 25);
    line2.setAttribute('y2', y - 25);
    line2.setAttribute('stroke', 'white');
    line2.setAttribute('stroke-width', '2');
```